# KeyError: 'driver' in print(response.request.meta['driver'].title)

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I get the error KeyError:'driver'.
I want to create a webcrawler using scrapy-selenium. My code looks like this:

```
class TestSpider(Spider):
name="test"
start_urls = ["http://crawler-test.com/mobile/dynamic"]

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SeleniumRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    print(response.request.meta['driver'].title)
```

In the settings of the crawler i added:

```
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('chromedriver')
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['--headless']
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800}
```

pretty much everything is from the scrapy-selenium documentation.
https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-selenium/

thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What is the expected result of this?: response.request.meta['driver'].title

Comment: As said i took pretty much everything from the docu-site. So i m not sure. But i thought that it would give me the title of the website ....

Comment: I think you're right, (<title>) but not familiar with scrapy/selenium... seems like that key's value should be a reference to your webdriver.   Maybe the webdriver doesn't exist, or "which" can't find it.  You might just put the path to it there.... where "SELNIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH" is... (or check that "which" is returning the path.)

Comment: I would also comment out this line: SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['--headless'] while you are troubleshooting.  That way if you don't see Chrome launching, you'll know something is wrong with the Selenium side of things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer found from @pcalkins comment

You have two ways to fix this:

**Fastest one**: Paste your chromedriver.exe file in the same directory that your spider is.

**Best one**: in SETTINGS.PY put your diver path in  `SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = YOUR PATH HERE`

This is you won't use which('chromediver')